# F string prefix in python giving a syntax error

Tags: python, string

I have a variable called method, it's value is POST but when I try to run `print(f"{method} method is used.")` it keeps giving a syntax error at the last double quote and I can't find the reason on why it does this. I am using python 3.5.2.

Comment: This line is fine. The syntax error is most likely caused by a previous line, but Python is only detecting it on this line. Can you post the full code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

F-strings were a new feature introduced in Python 3.6, so of course they're not going to work in 3.5.2.